# Output file not written in specific path using awk into a nextflow process

Tags: bash, awk, debian, nextflow

I would like to choose the path of different outputs obtained by AWK into a nextflow process, but i cannot get it. By writing $it after view i can obtain the output in the work directory but i would need to choose the $PATH. I have tried to change `$it to "${PathOutdir}/test_out.csv"` but doesn't work. Here i put a simple awk function inside the nextflow process. I should use the workflow function? Thanks in advance!

```
PathFile = "/home/pvellosillo/nextflow_test/test.csv"
InputCsv = file(PathFile)
PathOutdir = "/home/pvellosillo/nextflow_test"

process genesFilter {
tag "PathInputFile:${PathFile}"
input:
   path InputCsv
output:
  file("test_out.csv") into out_filter

shell:

"""
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print \$2}' $InputCsv > "test_out.csv"
"""
}

out_filter.view {"${PathOutdir}/test_out.csv"}
```

Comment: Note that by using publishDir {$PathOutdir} i get an output in a chosen directory but the files are symbolic links to the work directory instead of simply files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comment above:

> Note that by using publishDir {$PathOutdir} i get an output in a
> chosen directory but the files are symbolic links to the work
> directory instead of simply files

I think you are wanting the `'copy'` mode, so that the declared output files can be published to the publishDir. Make sure to avoid accessing output files in the publishDir:

> Files are copied into the specified directory in an asynchronous
> manner, so they may not be immediately available in the published
> directory at the end of the process execution. For this reason,
> downstream processes should not try to access output files through the
> publish directory, but through channels.

```
params.pathFile = "/home/pvellosillo/nextflow_test/test.csv"
params.publishDir = "/home/pvellosillo/nextflow_test"

InputCsv = file( params.pathFile )


process genesFilter {

    tag { InputCsv.name }

    publishDir(
        path: "${params.publishDir}/genesFilter",
        mode: 'copy',
    )

    input:
    path InputCsv

    output:
    path "test_out.csv" into out_filter

    shell:
    '''
    awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\\t" } { print $2 }' "!{InputCsv}" > "test_out.csv"
    '''
}

out_filter.view()
```

Also note that [shell](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#shell) script definitions require the use of single-quote `'` delimited strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. If I understand correctly i must specify the path of PublishDir at the beginning and adding "mode: copy" to get the output file in the specified path. I didn't know the shell definitions must be used by single-quote. And the "!{" must be written before input file into the awk script is due to is a file specified in params.pathFile PATH. Thanks again!

Comment: @PercevalVellosilloGonzalez, well, the 'copy' mode is a good default value in my opinion. This just copies the files (as declared in your output declaration) from the working directory (i.e. `./work`) to the publishDir. You may also wish to parameterize the mode, e.g. `mode: params.publishMode` and set `params.publishMode = 'copy'` above. Cheers!